# WebRTC picture capturing doesn't work on smartphones

Tags: webrtc, webcam, image-capture, android-image-capture

I'm trying to get an image capture from the front or back camera of my smartphone using the [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/). I used one of WebRTC samples for that. This code works perfectly in browsers on the computer, but on the smartphone with different operating systems (iOS, Android) I get a black screen in the tag `<video autoplay></video>`. I tried various browsers, in none of them the image capture function worked properly, everywhere a black screen was displayed. What should I do to capture the picture?

I have a http connection, all my smartphones and cameras work fine, so the problem is definitely in WebRTC (or in its use).

Answer (score 1):

For Safari, try adding playsinline to the video element. See [this thread](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/issues/929) for background information.

If that doesn't help you might want to check the mediastream as well as the video elements readyState property.